# React To-do List add categories

Tags: reactjs

I am building a to-do list in React JS and am mostly done.
However, I would like to add a category function so I can sort my to-dos into 3 sections (urgent, not urgent, do whenever).

Each categorized to-do will then be added to it's respective EXPANDABLE section as shown in the picture.

I would like to know what is the best way to structure this: To have 3 states (separate to-do lists) to track, or have each to-do have an 'urgency' property, or something else entirely?
Also, how do I make the category tab expandable/hide-able?
My main problem is I do not know how to split the to-dos into multiple categories and have them show up in the proper section using the urgency toggle (!!!!, !!, ...).

Current working code is here: https://github.com/brianjohnnychen/test123

[image]

Comment: Is there any code?

Comment: Yes, current code is here:
https://github.com/brianjohnnychen/test123